# Modal shows same video when open

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I have the following code:

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS Bin</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Open a modal dialog button -->
        <div class="container" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".video-dialog">
            <div class="container1">
                <img class="1" src="1.PNG">
            </div>
            <div class="container2">
                <img class="img2" src="1.PNG">
                <img class="img3" src="1.PNG">
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>



        <!-- Video Player Dialog -->
        <div class="modal fade video-dialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="videoDialogPlayer" class="vidflex"></div>
                        <div id="videoDialogPlayer2" class="vidflex"></div>
                        <div id="videoDialogPlayer3" class="vidflex"></div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            (function () {
                var el = document.createElement('script');
                el.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(el, s);

                var videoDialogPlayer;
                var videoDialogPlayer2;
                var videoDialogPlayer3;

                window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
                    videoDialogPlayer = new YT.Player('videoDialogPlayer', {
                        height: '390',
                        width: '640',
                        videoId: 'mRBaAYdJuLY',
                    });

                }
                window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
                    videoDialogPlayer2 = new YT.Player('videoDialogPlayer2', {
                        height: '390',
                        width: '640',
                        videoId: 'UvRs60UV6YI',
                    });

                }
                window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
                    videoDialogPlayer3 = new YT.Player('videoDialogPlayer3', {
                        height: '390',
                        width: '640',
                        videoId: 'RXT_bj_zDAI',
                    });

                }
            }());
        </script>
        <style>
            .container {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .container1 {
                display: flex;
                margin-top: 20px;
                margin-right: 20px;
            }

            .img2 {
                width: 90%;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
                padding-top: 20px;
            }

            .img3 {
                width: 90%
            }

            .container2 {
                height: 550px;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
        </style>
    </body>

    </html>
```

This displays three images and when clicked a modal open and a youtube video, however only the same video display on the modal, I can't fix to show the different videos. Btw I am using the youtube API to show the videos, so I do not know a way to do this with javascript only and not with bootstrap like now.

I put the

```js
 window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
```

global so now all videos appear, but at the same time. I need to show different ones each time

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

About your code: every time you call

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () { ... }
```

you assign the anonymous function defined with `function () { ... }` to the windows property `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`. This property can only have one value, so every time you assign an anonymous function you overwrite the previous one.

After your web page got loaded successfully, the function stored in the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` property gets executed and replaces the div-element with the given videoDialogPlayer id in your modal with an iframe-element. Since the property only remembers the last anonymous function you have assigned, you only see the third video.

For simplicity, I would suggest that you remove the hole anonymous function part and replace the div-elements in your modal with iFrames like the following:

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Its copied from the [YouTube documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) and They give the following notice:

> As an extra security measure, you should also include the origin
>   parameter to the URL, specifying the URL scheme (http:// or https://)
>   and full domain of your host page as the parameter value. While origin
>   is optional, including it protects against malicious third-party
>   JavaScript being injected into your page and hijacking control of your
>   YouTube player.

Now your modal shows all three videos at once. Since this is not what you want, we will fix this next.
Again for simplicity, I would suggest to put each video in its own modal and let become each image a modal-toggle. So each image opens its own modal.

In the end your code should look something like this:

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Open a modal dialog button -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container1">
        <img class="1" src="1.PNG" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".video-dialog">
      </div>
      <div class="container2">
        <img class="img2" src="1.PNG" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".video-dialog2">
        <img class="img3" src="1.PNG" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".video-dialog3">
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Video Player Dialog -->
    <div class="modal fade video-dialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mRBaAYdJuLY?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Video Player Dialog 2 -->
    <div class="modal fade video-dialog2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UvRs60UV6YI?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Video Player Dialog 3 -->
    <div class="modal fade video-dialog3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RXT_bj_zDAI?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <style>
      .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      
      .container1 {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }
      
      .img2 {
        width: 90%;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
      }
      
      .img3 {
        width: 90%
      }
      
      .container2 {
        height: 550px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    </style>
  </body>

  </html>
```

This is the simplest solution to your issue. From here on you can get arbitrarily sophisticated. For example, could you use only one modal and replace its body with the right video based on the image the user tapped.